# Change Look and Feel of JButton

Tags: swing, jbutton, nimbus

I would like use the nimbus button style in my application. I don't want change L&F. Only change the L&F of the button to use nimbus L&F. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better way, but the following utility class should work for you:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.LookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;


public class NimbusButton {
    private static LookAndFeel nimbus;

    public static JButton generateNimbusButton() {
        try {
            LookAndFeel current = UIManager.getLookAndFeel(); //capture the current look and feel

            if (nimbus == null) { //only initialize Nimbus once
                for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
                nimbus = UIManager.getLookAndFeel();
            }
            else
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(nimbus); //set look and feel to nimbus
            JButton button = new JButton(); //create the button
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(current); //return the look and feel to its original state
            return button;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new JButton();
        }
    }
}
```

The generateNimbusButton() method changes the look and feel to Nimbus, creates the button, then changes the look and feel back to whatever it was when the method was called.